# Can Hash be sorted by keys or values?

Tags: dictionary, hashtable, crystal-lang

Is it possible to sort [Hash](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/Hash.html) by key or by value in following code:

```
myhash.each_key do |key| 
   print myhash[key], "\t:\t", key, "\n" 
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting by keys:

```
myhash = {5 => "five", 3 => "three", 2 => "two", 4 => "four", 1 => "one"}

myhash.keys.sort.each do |key| 
  print myhash[key], "\t:\t", key, "\n" 
end
```

produces

```
one     :   1
two     :   2
three   :   3
four    :   4
five    :   5
```

Sorting by value is a bit more effort:

```
myhash.to_a.sort { |item1, item2| item1[1] <=> item2[1] }.each do |item|
  puts item.join("\t:\t")
end
```

produces

```
5   :   five
4   :   four
1   :   one
3   :   three
2   :   two
```

If you want the outcomes in value:key order, change

```
puts item.join("\t:\t")
```

to

```
puts item.reverse.join("\t:\t")
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Crystal `Hash` preserves order of insertion, it is possible to actually make a sorted `Hash`:

```
myhash.to_a.sort.to_h
```

To sort by values,

```
myhash.to_a.sort_by { |k, v| v }.to_h
```

To sort in-place, it's a bit bulkier:

```
myhash = {5 => "five", 3 => "three", 2 => "two", 4 => "four", 1 => "one"}

entries = myhash.to_a.sort
myhash.clear
entries.each { |k, v| myhash[k] = v }
```